# edit user-dirs.dirs folder location

Tags: root, drive, location

i'd like to change the location of the main Music folder location manually in user-dirs-dirs from "$HOME/Music" to the root directory of my sata ssd /dev/sda1, but i am unsure on how to point to this root directory of this drive, i tried /dev/sda1 but this didn't work as intended.

my main ssd with the ubuntu OS on it is /dev/nvme0n1p2

thanks for any help.

Matthieu

Comment: You need to mount the disk somewhere.

Comment: The drive probably *is* already mounted somewhere. Use `df` to find out where, and use that as the starting point for your music directory.

Comment: @ Jus:i checked df, it wasn't mounted yet, so indeed i added a mount point as described by Pilot6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount your disk to some directory first.

For example run:

```
sudo mkdir /media/HDD
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/HDD
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/HDD
```

Now you can use `/media/HDD` as the root directory of your disk.

To make the disk permanently mounted, you need to edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: i created the mount point as you suggested and edited fstab. it is now mounted on reboot, but i do not yet understand the right format in which to edit the Music line in user-dirs-dirs. i tried "$media/HDD" and "/media/HDD". neither seems correct.

Comment: i used the command sudo xdg-user-dirs-update --set MUSIC "/media/HDD", which worked.